# i'm doing snapshot testing on Login screen why jest giving me error on map screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mapbox-gl

Login.test.js

```
require('react-native')

import React from 'react'
import { create,act } from 'react-test-renderer'
import Login from '../src/components/pages/auth/LoginPage'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import App from '../App'
import MapboxGL from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps'
import { setAccessToken } from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

test('snapshot', () => {
  rootTree = renderer.create(<Login/>).toJSON()
  // expect(rootTree).toMatchSnapshot();
})

jest.mock('@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps', () => ({   
  setAccessToken: jest.fn(),
}));
  
describe('test', () => {
  it('should set access token', () => {
    // Call the function that sets the access token
    MapboxGL.default.setAccessToken('pk.eyJ1Ijoia21234Jja3U3dngzcmU1ajJjMndwaWZpcnRsc099yIn0.tVk9sh1nGAhc987668X3Q');
  
    // Check that the function was called with the correct access token
      
    expect(MapboxGL.default.setAccessToken).toHaveBeenCalledWith('pk.eyJ1Ijoia21234Jja3U3dngzcmU1ajJjMndwaWZpcnRsc099yIn0.tVk9sh1nGAhc987668X3Q');
  });
});
```

> ```
> ● Test suite failed to run
>
>     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAccessToken')
>
>       34 | // import Geolocation from "react-native-geolocation-service";
>       35 |
>     > 36 | MapboxGL.setAccessToken(
>          |          ^
>       37 |   "pk.eyJ1Ijoia21234Jja3U3dngzcmU1ajJjMndwaWZpcnRsc099yIn0.tVk9sh1nGAhc987668X3Q"
>       38 | );
>       39 |
>
>       at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/pages/main/map/map.js:36:10)
>       at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/pages/main/tab.js:4:1)
>
> Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
> Tests:       0 total
> Snapshots:   0 total
> Time:        5.184 s
> Ran all test suites.
> ```

Login.js

```
import {
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Dimensions,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  Linking,
  View,
} from "react-native";
 
export default function LoginPage({ navigation }) {
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
  const height = Dimensions.get("window").height;
  
  return (
    <ScrollView
      contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
    >
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{ userName: "", password: "" }}
          validationSchema={LoginValidationSchema}
          onSubmit={(values) => login(values, dispatch)}
        >
          {(props) => {
            const { values, handleSubmit, handleChange, errors } = props;
            return (
              <View
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                }}
              >
                <Logo />
                <View
                  style={{
                    paddingBottom: height / 30,
                    paddingTop: height / 35,
                  }}
                >
                  <Text
                    style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold" }}
                  >
                    Log in to your account
                  </Text>
                </View>
                {login_res.error ? (
                  <AuthErrorMessage message="Email or password incorrect" />
                ) : null}
                {error ? <AuthErrorMessage message={error} /> : <></>}

                <NormalInput
                  name="userName"
                  value={values.userName}
                  onChange={handleChange("userName")}
                  label="Email"
                  errorMessage={errors.userName}
                />
                <Password
                  label="Password"
                  name="password"
                  isLoginPage={true}
                  value={values.password}
                  onChange={handleChange("password")}
                  errorMessage={errors.password}
                />
                <View style={{justifyContent: "flex-end"}}>
                <Text
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ResetPassword")}
                  style={{ color: colors.inputLabelColor, marginLeft: width / 2.3,top:scaledSize(4) }}
                >
                  Forgot password
                </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ marginTop: height / 20 }}>
                <AuthButton
                  loading={login_res.loading}
                  label="Sign in"
                  onClick={handleSubmit}
                />
                </View>
                
                <View style={{ paddingTop: height / 40 }}>
                  {loading ? (
                    <Spinner />
                  ) : (
                   
                  )}
                </View>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => nav()}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: colors.inputLabelColor,
                      paddingTop: height / 30,
                    }}
                  >
                    I don 't have an account.
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        color: GLOBAL_COLORS.LIGHT_PURPLE,
                        fontWeight: '800'
                      }}
                    >
                      {`   Signup.`}
                    </Text>
                  </Text>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              </View>
            );
          }}
        </Formik>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Map.js

```
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import MapboxGL, { Logger } from "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps";
// import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native'
import { useTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { memo, useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Dimensions, View, Alert, Text } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { socket } from "../../../../service/socket";
import { getUserRequest } from "../../../../redux/actions/user/user.action";
import {
  getUnseenUserAnnouncement,
  getUserAnnouncement,
  updateSingleSeenAnnouncement,
} from "../../../../redux/actions/announcement/announcement.action";
import GeolocationLib from "react-native-geolocation-service";
import { RESET_ADD_MEMBERS_STATE } from "../../../../redux/actions/group/group.type";
    
MapboxGL.setAccessToken(
  "pk.eyJ1IjoiazcmU1ajJjMndwaWZpcnRscHNyIn0.tVk9sh18cPu989cKCA8X3Q"
);
    
function Map({ showNotification, route, navigation }) {
)}
    
export default memo(Map);
```

Getting issue while running test case using Jest I'm trying to do snapshot testing on login  component but why i'm getting error on map.js component I didn't use map on login screen.
Even I'm getting an error on bottom-navigation too.
I used map component on home screen and other some screen but didn't use on login screen.